# fancyBox popup showing up under another element

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

I used the FancyBox plugin to load a Vimeo movie into a popup, but the popup is blocked by some part of the HTML on the page.

Live link: [click here](http://www.devideovakvrouw.nl/) : it's when you click on the slider image underneath the yellow bar.

I tried things like Z-index but that does not seem to work. I think it's something very simple but I can't seem to find it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your style.css file (line 278):

```
#masthead{
    z-index: 99988;
}
```

That z-index is rendering your header at the 99988th level, which is way above where the overlay is attempting to render (at the 8010th level [line 180 of jquery.fancybox.css]). Set it to 1 instead (or something small):

```
#masthead{
    z-index: 1;
}
```

And the video is no longer covered up.